# How to use stream api for repeatable actions

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to know how to shorten my code with the help of Stream Api.
Let's say I have method like this:

```
public static void createFile( String directoryPath, String fileName )
```

And I would like to call this method 5 times with the same parameters. For example

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Utils.createFile(getDirectoryLocation(), "test.txt");
        }
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).forEach(Utils::someMethod);
```

But here I am passing one integer value to method. Anyone can give me some hints or answers?

Comment: You know that while shortening might be true, performance wise this may lack behind a the simple loop.

Comment: You might be right, but for the learning purposes it is nice to have this knowledge.

Comment: well...Streams won't help you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Streams aren't really helpful here, a simple loop would be better IMO. But if you *really* wanted to, you could write it via a lambda (ignoring x... ):

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).forEach(x -> Utils.createFile(getDirectoryLocation(), "test.txt"));
```

I guess one more ugly way could be:

```
Stream.generate(() -> "test.txt")
            .limit(5)
            .forEach(x -> Utils.createFile(getDirectoryLocation(), x));
```

Or better:

```
Collections.nCopies(5, "test.txt")
           .forEach(x -> Utils.createFile(getDirectoryLocation(), x));
```

Comment: Just a choice of traditional preference `range(0, 5)`...and now I am wondering *"ugly"* means what? readability(of course IMHO) or performance as well?

Comment: @nullpointer I was really going into the readability thing yes, a simple loop would be a lot more readable. I only showed it since the OP said in comments for learning purposes...

Comment: @nullpointer I’d consider `range(0, 5)` preferable too, especially as the OP’s loop does exactly that (`for(int i = 0; i < 5;…`). But why on Earth does someone want to create the same file five times?

Comment: @nullpointer performance may also be hampered. A simple for loop is always going to be faster than a stream for this kinda of job.